# useContext error : Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am new to useContext hook. I am getting errors like `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')` while using useContext hook.

Please help me regarding it.

My code:

### noteContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const noteContext = createContext();

export default noteContext;
```

### NoteState.js

```
import NoteContext from "./noteContext";
import { useState } from "react";
import App from '../../App'

const NoteState = async (props)=>{
     const [state, setState] = useState({
         name: "nk",
         class: "8a"
     });

    return (
        <>
        <NoteContext.Provider value={state}>
            <App/>
        </NoteContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}

export default NoteState;
```

Here I'm trying to use it and resulting in getting an error:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import noteContext from '../context/notes/noteContext'


const About = () => {
    const mynote = useContext(noteContext)

    return (
        <div>
            This is About
            This is About {mynote.name} and he is in class {mynote.class}
        </div>
    )
}

export default About
```

Comment: You are making the NoteState  component function asynchronus, It should be a normal function. maybe this is causing the error

Comment: Did you try to console log the note context to check if it is being initialized

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use like this

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const NoteContext = createContext({});

export const NoteProvider = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return <NoteContext.Provider value={props}>{children}</NoteContext.Provider>;
};
```

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { NoteProvider } from "./noteContext";
import App from "./App";

function Start() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "valya"
  });
  return (
    <NoteProvider state={state}>
      <App />
    </NoteProvider>
  );
}

export default Start;
```

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { NoteContext } from "./noteContext";

const About = () => {
  const state = useContext(NoteContext);
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(state)}</div>;
};

export default About;
```

your export is also wrong  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB2Gx.png

and this is result https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fn2b.png

component export can't be start with lowercase